# QDropEvent to copy temporary files from temporary folder

Tags: qt

In my Qt application on Windows, I have a widget which serves as a drag-and-drop target for files or folders dragged over from other applications. When the widget gets drop action and paths from MIME, it copies the files and processes them in a certain way. It works well when copying ordinary files or folders e.g. from Windows Explorer or from Total Commander. It would be also nice to accept files directly extracted from archive using e.g. 7Z (7zip). When I open the archive in 7Z application and drag and drop it onto my widget, the widget receives `QDropEvent` with action `Qt::CopyAction`, MIME formats `("text/uri-list")` and a vector of paths (URIs). The problem is that the paths lead to a temporary folder somewhere in `..../AppData/Local/Temp/....etc.` and before I manage to process the files someone (I assume 7Z) deletes them immediately. I do not know ho to get more time to process them or communicate to the drag source to not delete them. It seems that some other programs serving as drop targets manage this issue well - e.g. Windows Explorer or Total Commander can serve as drop targets for 7Z without any problems. Any ideas how they are doing it? Can the same be done in Qt application?

UPDATE:
I have found that the extracted temporary files are not deleted until my application's event loop does not finish handling of the drop event (regardless of whether I call `event->acceptProposedAction()` or not). So if I would process all the files in the event handler, it would be fine. But processing (or even copying large files) takes time and doing it in the main thread would block the GUI, therefore I am doing it in another thread. Which means the event is handled and 7Z informed sooner than the other thread finishes. Is there any way to postpone the finishing of handling of this drop event, i.e. to postpone the response to 7Z?

Comment: Have you tried locking the directory/file or opening a file handle as soon as possible and preventing the file from being deleted?

Comment: @Itay Grudev There can be many files, so locking or openning handles may take time and I also do want to avoid data races with other program who will be faster. And I want to let the other program eventually delete the data, because my program has no clue about whether the data should be left in there or be deleted.

Comment: You could start a new `QEventLoop` in your event handler. This way the event stays "active", but you can still process the files asynchronously while keeping the ui responsive

Comment: That is an interesting solution. Could you please tell us if it worked @V.K.?

Comment: Well, I am not going to implement this, this feels like a very ugly hack. This would mean to have event loop inside event handler called by other event loop. This is not what event loops are designed for. For example what will do the other events in the queue in the first event loop? Will they wait as well? This will certainly break something and will be hard to debug. I think there must be a better way and I am going to find it. I think I will have to look at some details Windows API and how it handles the drop mechanism, how my app informs 7Z that the drop operation has been finished.